# ansible playbook with for loop not working as expected

Tags: bash

Trying to create a playbook to check docker container logs but it doesn't iterate over the for loop

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: Check container logs
        shell: |
          for i in "web_container_node{1..5}"; do
             echo ""
             echo "#### ${i} ####"
             echo ""
             docker logs --tail 10 ${i}
          done
        args:
          executable: /bin/bash
```

but the output literally passes the container name as in the playbook without iteration

```
No such container: "web_container_node{1..5}",
```

Comment: This is not an Ansible problem. The script behaves the same in Bash regardless of how you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

the way you use bash expansion won't work, even in bash, I suggest you do the this way.

```
  - name: Check container logs
    shell: |
      for i in {1..5}; do
         echo "webcontainer${i}"
         echo ""
         echo "#### ${i} ####"
         echo ""
         docker logs --tail 10 ${i}
      done
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: great, if so, you can indicate the answer is valid (the tick) and is useful (upvote)